# How should AppBars be hidden after button click?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store, appbar

The Windows Store app that I am working on has two AppBars on the main page. One on top for navigation and another below for commands.

Obviously, I want the AppBars to close after the new command button is clicked. The following code works, but it seems rather ungainly:

```
private void appbarNew_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    App.viewModel.newModel();

    this.TopAppBar.IsOpen = false;
    this.BottomAppBar.IsOpen = false;
}
```

I assumed that the AppBars would be closed automatically or at least there'd be some sort of "handled" boolean in the event object that could be used to accomplish this. What is the proper solution here?

Answer (score 1):

You can control with this code. You can check and also you can set IsOpen with bool.

Tal Malaki's solution just hide or visible it, this code is the solution what you're looking for

```
ApplicationBarName.IsOpen = false / true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give you AppButton a name like AppBtn.
Then try this on the click event:

```
AppBtn.Visiblity=Visibilty.Hidden;
```

Comment: This just hides the single button and it does so permanently. What I want to do is collapse both AppBars until they are opened again by the user. This can be accomplished using the code I included above, but it seems very awkward.